# Ruby on rails: Id attribute of input elements generated by form helpers, with non english values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, form-helpers, non-english

Some Rails form-helpers (for instance 'radio_button' helper), append the element's value to the generated id string.

But if the value is not in English - nothing gets appended to the id string. This may result in multiple elements (all with non English values) having the same id attribute.

What's the recommended way to tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post, but it's coming up first in Google so I thought I'd spare some other rails developers a bit of misery by giving a code example of how to get this to work.

```
<%= radio_button_tag "name", "value", false, :class => "test-class", :id => "radio-id" %>
```

I just spent 20 mins trying to figure out how to do it and realised I was missing the 3rd parameter (checked). Aaargh!

Rails documentation here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own custom `id` in the `options` hash

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button